# How can I write a javascript that generates random numbers automatically every second?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random, setinterval

God! I'm going nuts...‍♂️

I want a **javascript code** whereby in an array of numbers for example (202,157), the numbers that generate or change randomly **every second** from a minimum of 100 to a maximum of 600 are **only the last three** (157 for instance), and every previously generated random numbers go below the newly generated random numbers.

For instance, if the first number generated is 202,157 the second will probably be 202,364 or 202,176 probably, but the first three numbers (202) don't change.

Take this set for example

202,411

202,203

202,422

202,301

202,157

They are separated by a comma but only the last three numbers change randomly.

I've tried my possible best, but mehn, I don't even know what I'm writing anymore. I'm going nuts.

```
var random = Math.random[min,max];

     function getRandomInt(min, max){
            document.getElementById("ballerii").innerHTML = random;
     } 
     
setInterval(random, 1000);
```

Please anyone that understands what I seek, can help me find please. If you know anyone that can help too, please refer him/her. Thank you.

Comment: You need to put the `random` assignment inside the function, so you get a new number each time.

Comment: Also, the first argument to `setInterval` needs to be the function name, not `random`.

Comment: I still don't understand sir.

Comment: `Math.random` is a function, not an array, you call it with `()`. It doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: [The OP keeps circling around this topic for the last 5 days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18149314/wiggins?tab=questions). Please OP before starting a new question on that matter at least try to implement some of the former ideas into the overall problem. Stay in one thread. Keep asking questions there until the problem could be solved. Open a new one only in case of an entirely new approach / problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Math.random()` inside the function to get a new random number.

`Math.random()` doesn't take arguments to specify a range. See [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) for how you can do that.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function showRandomInt() {
  let newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  newdiv.innerText = "202," + getRandomInt(100, 600);
  document.getElementById("ballerii").insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", newdiv);
}

setInterval(showRandomInt, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="ballerii">
</div>
```